# How to make functional wrapper without parameters on F#?

Tags: f#, wrapper

here is my code :

```
let go thriller =
    work.ListPos.Clear()
    thriller
    work.Thread.Start()

member X.Start() =
    work.ListPos.Add <| new Packet( connector.Authorize("admin","1") ) |> go
```

So it doesn't work. I used wrapper with parameter like this :

```
let inconnection thriller   = 
    using <| new SqlConnection(insql)  <| fun X -> X.Open(); thriller X;

inconnection <| fun X ->
```

I can't use it this way without parameters because I got no X (parameter) but how to create lambda without parameters ?

*Thank you.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can see, you're trying to implement the "hole in the middle" pattern - that is, run some initialization, then run a function specified by the user and then run some cleanup.

As dahlbyk already pointed out, you need to pass your `go` operation a *function* of type `unit -> unit`. This can be written like this:

```
let go thriller =
    work.ListPos.Clear()
    thriller()
    work.Thread.Start()

// Use it like this:
go (fun () ->
  work.ListPos.Add(new Packet( connector.Authorize("admin","1"))
)
```

**Aside.** Your other example isn't really idiomatic F# code. The `using` function can be replaced with a `use` keyword, which is significantly easier to use:

```
let inconnection thriller   = 
    use conn = new SqlConnection(insql) 
    conn.Open()
    thriller conn

inconnection (fun conn -> ...)
```

**More tricky option.**
Alternatively, you can also use the `use` keyword for other things than disposing of resources like SQL connections. This could make your `go` function even nicer (but it depends on your particular case). The idea is that you'll be able to write:

```
use u = go()  // work.ListPos.Clear() gets called here
work.ListPos.Add(new Packet(connector.Authorize("Admin", "1")))
// work.Thread.Start() gets called automatically when 'u' variable goes out of scope
```

To do this, you need to define `go` as a function that returns `IDisposable` that performs the cleanup:

```
let go () =
  work.ListPos.Clear()
  { new IDisposable with
      member x.Dispose() = work.Thread.Start() }
```

Comment: Tricky option is interesting. So then can I make  using <| go  <| fun () -> ... as I don't need variable. I need to try it. I like to use "using" because it has begin and end and I like to have this ability to separate some things in my code.

Comment: In the tricky option, you need a variable even though it is not used anymore (this is just a property of how `use` works). However, you can use it even if you want to have better control over the scope. You can enclose an expression in parens and indent it further from the left to define the scope explicitly.

Comment: I suppose you could use tricky option _and_ `using`, but that's probably not good idea (it just makes things more complex). If you want to use lambdas, I recommend just `go (fun () -> ...)` (as in the first version), because that's more straightforward.

Answer (score 6):

Use `()` for an empty lambda parameter list or for an empty body:

```
fun () -> ()  // unit -> unit
```